# Binary Classification of a series of data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, categorical-data

I have came across a binary classification problem which I dont think falls under traditional binary classification. So just wanted to share with you guys to get some more ideas.

I have a series of data records which is in a chronological order. For simplicity lets say I have 100 data records and I have a target value as 1 or 0 for every consecutive 10 data values.

e.g. data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Training data would look like this:

[1,2,3] => 1,
[2,3,4] => 0,
[3,4,5] => 0,
[4,5,6] => 0,
[5,6,7] => 1  and so on and so forth. please note that order of values does matters

I am currently struggling on how to handle this idea. Is there any Machine learning tools that can handle this? like Amazon Machine Learning or BigML etc.

My approach:

I am thinking of using some kind of hash function that can hash the series to specific value and that value can be used for one to one binary classification. However I am not sure if I am going in the right direction.

EDIT: More precisely I have a data consisting of 5 numerical features. Each instance of these 5 feature values are coming in a timely manner like every second. This instance or vector of 5 feature values independent of each other does not have any a significance however when consider in a group they have (In this case group is consecutive 100 vectors). These groups can be labeled as either 1 or 0 based on their characteristics. Now I wanted to build a classifier for this that can in future classify the data series of 100 instance as 1 or 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see what's so unusual about this problem, really. Your features would be the first, second, and so on values in the series.

Comment: In general, this problem is called time series classification.

Comment: @Sycorax: "time series classification" could also refer to classifying time series, which is a different problem than time-ordered classification data.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to forecast future classifications? Do you have additional explanatory data (time series or other)? Plus: if you already *know* that each block of ten observations will have the same classification, then you could simply take every tenth data point without losing any information. Is there any specific reason why you don't want to do that?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I'm not clear on the distinction you're making. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Sycorax: there is *time series classification*, which classifies time series, e.g., into seasonal, trended, intermittent etc. *Time series clustering* is similar, but typically unsupervised. What the OP here seems to be looking at here is *time series of categorical data*, where the category (or classification) of something can change over time. E.g., a vehicle sensor could have a time series of the state of the ignition, which is sometimes ON and sometimes OFF.

Comment: First of all thank you guys for all your responses and @StephanKolassa I have added an Edit in the post. Hope that make things more clear

Comment: is there a reason, why you cannot hard-code/automate such stuff for the combinations in the train data?

Comment: To be honest, I'm still a little confused on what your data are, and what you would like the output to look like. Could you edit your question to add some toy data? Plus, I had hoped we might have something in [questions tagged both time-series and categorical-data](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series+categorical-data), but that search seems to be rather unhelpful. (Most [tag:categorical-data] tags on those questions refer to the *causal* variables, not the *outcomes*.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa so the data is of numerical type, all the 5 features. and the output would be 0 or 1 based on what classifier predicts for any given 100 instances/vectors

Comment: So, do you have five time series, or a single one that takes one of five different categories at each point in time? And are you interested in forecasting the future development of this particular series, or of a new series? Please edit your question to include some toy data, perhaps of length 20 instead of 100.

Comment: okay so this is not a 5 different time series data. At any point in time I get a single value from 5 different sensors and more precisely I get these values every second as I mentioned and this makes one instance. These instances are my time series data. Now I wanna predict whether a group of any given 100 instances are dangerous or non-dangerous.

Comment: I used dtw; dynamic time series wrapping for time series classification and it helped for me.